# get website name from banner clicking

Tags: asp.net

I put a banner in another website. when user clicks that banner then he redirect destination url. i that desination website i want get website name where user clicks banner.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put the name of that website in the url. Make them refer to `http://yourdomain.com/bannerclick?referrer=theirdomain.com`.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx